# how to pass parameters to thread by using 3.5 c#.net

Tags: c#, multithreading

here i am trying to generate a dynamic threads by reading xml document for each attribute id,but am facing a problem that how to pass parameter to dynamic thread,for which related elements of the particular attribute, is there any way to send parameters? please advice

in below thread i am calling a dowork method, i have to pass parameters of elements of which particular attribute id how can i do that?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
var currentDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(string.Format(Path.Combine(currentDir, "Hosts.xml")));
var threads = new List<Thread>();

foreach (XElement host in xDoc.Descendants("Host"))
{
    var hostID = (int) host.Attribute("id");
    var extension = (string) host.Element("Extension");
    var folderPath = (string) host.Element("FolderPath");
    var thread = new Thread(DoWork)
                     {
                         Name = string.Format("samplethread{0}", hostID)
                     };
    thread.Start(new FileInfo
                     {
                         HostId = hostID,
                         Extension = extension,
                         FolderPath = folderPath
                     });
    threads.Add(thread);
    }
   //Carry on with your other work, then wait for worker threads
   threads.ForEach(t => t.Join());
}

   static void DoWork(object threadState)
     {
       var fileInfo = threadState as FileInfo;
            if (fileInfo != null)
             {
               //Do stuff here
             }
      }

      class FileInfo
         {
           public int HostId { get; set; }
           public string Extension { get; set; }
           public string FolderPath { get; set; }
         }
```

How do I call a method that takes multiple parameters in a thread. I have a method called

```
 Send(string arg1, string arg2, string arg3)
```

thats the reason i have asked you guys for any solution to pass parameters,note here my threading methodology was designed by dynamical manner, any suggestion please ?

Comment: Take a look at `ParametrizedThreadStart`.

Comment: @CodeCaster he's already using that, since `DoWork` takes `object threadState`

Comment: which begs the question, of course... since you are already successfully passing a parameter... what is the actual question?

Comment: Probably looking for a way to send a message to the running thread

Comment: @SandeepSinghRawat yeah, How do I call a method that takes multiple parameters in a thread. I have a method called Send(string arg1, string arg2, string arg3)

Comment: why dont you pass an array of object to the thread start? or create a custom object wrapping all the required values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already passing in parameters just fine.  I'm not sure if I understand your question but

> i have to pass parameters of elements of which particular attribute id
>   how can i do that?

It sounds like all you need is an `if statement` inside your `foreach`.  You are already looping through and creating threads/passing params.  Are you just asking how to make sure each item has a particular attribute id?  If so - just make it

```
foreach (XElement host in xDoc.Descendants("Host"))
{
    var hostID = (int) host.Attribute("id");
    // Check ID here
    if(hostID != ID_I_WANT) 
        continue;
    var extension = (string) host.Element("Extension");
    var folderPath = (string) host.Element("FolderPath");
    var thread = new Thread(DoWork)
                     {
                         Name = string.Format("samplethread{0}", hostID)
                     };
    thread.Start(new FileInfo
                     {
                         HostId = hostID,
                         Extension = extension,
                         FolderPath = folderPath
                     });
    threads.Add(thread);
    }
   //Carry on with your other work, then wait for worker threads
   threads.ForEach(t => t.Join());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to use TPL rather than starting your own threads?

If so you could just do this:

```
xDoc.Descendants("Host").AsParallel().ForAll(host =>
{
    DoWork(new FileInfo
    {
        HostId = (int)xe.Attribute("id"),
        Extension = (string)xe.Element("Extension"),
        FolderPath = (string)xe.Element("FolderPath"),
    });
});
```

Or did I miss the point of this question?