# how to set timer for each different thread in window service

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

trying to set timer for each different threads with different timings ,  as far as i know if we set a timer in main method the same will works for all the threads, so i want to know how to set timer for each different thread with out killing the threads, kindly advice on this please

```
static Timer _timer;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   _timer = new Timer(10000);
   _timer.Enabled = true;
   _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
 }
```

the above pasted code will do job for all of the threads will run for every ten sec, how ever all threads will run for every ten sec by the timer in main method, my concern is have to set timer for each thread with different timing

Summary:

why i asked like this question, here i have requirement of window service,what is to do means,For example in a window service having a three different threads(XYZ,ABC,PQR), if i start a service,all the three threads to be intialized and those threads should to be acts as For which based on timer settings which we are passing from the app config,these thread has to be fire based on the timings has setted,kindly advice

Comment: which "different threads"? are you planning on instantiating additional threads? I'm having trouble understanding how you want these threads to interact, perhaps you could expand a little on what you're trying to do.

Comment: @bkr yeah i am using in my service three different threads for example ThreadABC,ThreadXYZ,ThreadPQR for these i want to set timer differently one thread to be run 2 min,another as 5 min like that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start some threads after a given time, you can use System.Threading.Timer.

```
int[] times = new int[] { 10000, 14000, 17000 };
foreach (int time in times)
{
System.Threading.Timer t = new System.Threading.Timer(MyTimerCallback, null, time, 0);
...
}

private void MyTimerCallback(object state)
{
  //Do some awesome stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use the `[ThreadStatic]` attribute?
This attribute defines that the veriable it coupled with will not be shared between threads, and a copy of him will be created for each thread.

```
[ThreadStatic]
static Timer _timer;

void MyThreadStartMethod()
{
    _timer=new Timer(value);
    ...
}
```

And also, i don't see any threads in your code. The `Main` method is called by the CLR to start the application, and runs each time in a different process.

Comment: thank your valuable reply, but i am little confused to use the above your snippet code in the program can please help me out on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11017251/how-to-set-timer-for-dynamic-thread-by-passing-parameters-by-using-c-net

Comment: y because i m trying set timer setting of each theard different timings, for more clarification i am using a dynamic thearding you can by click the above comment,kindly advise

Comment: OK, in these question was the problem that the thread finished the work and died. When the main thread of a program has finished, the program closes. All the Timer threads died also. You must let the threads run in a loop, as answered there.

Comment: yeah correct, i must let the threads run in a loop based on timer,my assumption is by avoiding a timer in the main method, while generating dynamic thread in that time it self if any possibilities set timer differently for each thread,then those thread run based on timing in a loop,if you want to have a glance on my code i have already posted by link in the first comment